# Making POST request using RESTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, restkit

I'm trying to make a POST request using restKit, but I can't.

My code is something like this:

```
    NSString *urlAddTask;
    urlAddTask = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some URL"];

    RKObjectManager* mgr = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    mgr.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
    [mapping mapKeyPath: @"name"       toAttribute:@"name"         ];

    RKObjectMapping* mappingForSerialization = [mapping inverseMapping];

    [mgr.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:mappingForSerialization forClass:[NSManagedObject class]];

    [mgr.router routeClass:[NSManagedObject class] toResourcePath:urlAddTask forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    Task *t=[[Task alloc]init];
    t.name=@"One name";

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[Task class] toResourcePath:@"/tasks" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    [mgr postObject:t delegate:nil/*self*/];
```

When I execute this code I get this error:

```
    *** Assertion failure in -[RKObjectLoader prepareURLRequest], /myAppRoute/Libraries/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKObjectLoader.m:304
2013-02-14 17:12:25.202 Aplication[1929:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must provide a serialization mapping for objects of type 'Task''
```

I think that I'm doing a lot of thing bad. I'm looking for a good example about how to make a POST but I didn't find any post that help me to do my request.

Can you help me with my code o giving me a good example about how to do this?

Thank you!

---

### UPDATE

I updated the serialization line like you say. Then I had this error:

```
2013-02-15 10:16:45.009 myApp[829:c07] W restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:241 Unable to find parser for MIME Type 'text/html'
2013-02-15 10:16:45.009 myApp[829:c07] W restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:262 Encountered unexpected response with status code: 200 (MIME Type: text/html)
```

Then I tried to change my serializationMIMEType from RKMIMETypeJSON to RKMIMETypeXML with this line:

```
mgr.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeXML;
```

And now the error is something like this:

```
2013-02-15 10:20:01.315 myApp[873:c07] -[RKXMLParserLibXML stringFromObject:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86ae910
2013-02-15 10:20:01.316 myApp[873:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RKXMLParserLibXML stringFromObject:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86ae910'
```

How I said I'm sure that i'm doing a lot of things bad. I'm very lost with that.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak on other errors, but as the exception message indicates, your serialization mapping is missing for the `Task` class. You should probably change

```
[mgr.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:mappingForSerialization forClass:[NSManagedObject class]];
```

to

```
[mgr.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:mappingForSerialization forClass:[Task class]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code seems to be a little bit of chaos and some things are wrong.

```
// Set url of webservice
NSURL *taskURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demopath.com"];   

// Set object manager with base url
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] init];
objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:taskURL];

// Set accepted data type
[objectManager setSerializationMIMEType:@"application/json"];
[objectManager setAcceptMIMEType:@"application/json"];
// [objectManager.client setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; // Optional

// Set store 
RKManagedObjectStore* objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"yourFileName.xml"];
objectManager.objectStore = objectStore;

// Set route
[objectManager.router routeClass:[Task class] toResourcePath:@"/tasks" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST]; // Set path for posting objects

// Set mapping
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Task class]];
[mapping mapKeyKath:@"nameServer" toAttribute:@"nameClient"]; // If webservice and local attributes got different names, first is the receiving one, second the local one

// Init your new object
Task *task = [Task new];
task.nameClient = @"Hello world";

// Send post request to webservice
[objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[mapping inverseMapping] forClass:[Task class]]; // Set inverse mapping on post reques   
[objectManager postObject:task usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader)
 {
     loader.backgroundPolicy = RKRequestBackgroundPolicyContinue; // Continues request when app is moving to background
     // loader.resourcePath = @"/tasks"; // // Optional, because it has been configured in the routing
     // loader.objectMapping = [objectManager.mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Task class]]; // Optional, because it has been configured before
     loader.delegate = self;

     loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {
      NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", objects);
  };
     loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"It Failed: %@", error);
  };
 }];
```

When your webservice returns `200` and the MIME type `text/html` it seems to be that your trying to call a webservice that needs authorization (because the webservice returns a login page). If you need authorization for your request, add the following method before the post request.

```
// Set authorization
objectManager.client.username = @"yourUsername";
objectManager.client.password = @"yourPassword";
objectManager.client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic; // Change like you need it
```

Hope you get things running.